# Laravel 5: Is there a non-case sensitive way to sort a collection by an attribute?

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, eloquent

I'm struggling to sort an Eloquent collection using the `sortBy()` method. The issue is that the sorting is case sensitive and it first retrieves the uppercase results and then the lowercase ones, but what I'm trying to achieve is to sort every item no matter if it's uppercase or lowercase.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`sortBy()` second argument allows you to set some flags regarding on how the sorting should be handled.

Flags are exactly the same as PHP `sort()` native function.

> - **SORT_REGULAR** - compare items normally (don't change types)
> - **SORT_NUMERIC** - compare items numerically
> - **SORT_STRING** - compare items as strings
> - **SORT_LOCALE_STRING** - compare items as strings, based on the current locale. It uses the locale, which can be changed using
>     setlocale()
> - **SORT_NATURAL** - compare items as strings using "natural ordering" like natsort()
> - **SORT_FLAG_CASE** - can be combined (bitwise OR) with SORT_STRING or SORT_NATURAL to sort strings case-insensitively
>
> source: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

You could try by using `$collection->sortBy('key', SORT_NATURAL|SORT_FLAG_CASE)`.

Comment: I had a need for this solution across many files, so decided to put @GiamPy's solution into a macro so I could call `$collection->iSortBy('key')` on any collection to save time. To do this, inside the register() method of one of your ServiceProviders, add the following: `Collection::macro('iSortBy', function ($callback, $options = SORT_REGULAR, $descending = false) { $options |= SORT_NATURAL|SORT_FLAG_CASE; return $this->sortBy($callback, $options, $descending);});`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a simple list of values and want to sort them ignoring the case, you can also use `sort()` instead of `sortBy()` with a callback function like so:

```
$collection->sort(function($a, $b){
    return strtolower($a) <=> strtolower($b);
});
```